# Postgresql to pyspark like operator

Tags: postgresql, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I have a postgres code like this and I want it to convert to pyspark but I am having problem on what to put inside my like operator

[image]

My pyspark code is something like this

```
(
customer.select('first_name', 'last_name')
    .where(F.col('email').like(F.concat(F.col('first_name'), F.lit('.'), F.col('last_name'), F.lit('@sakilacustomer.org'))).show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code with just where and concat worked fine for me

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import * 
tdf=spark.createDataFrame([("abc","def", "abc.def@test.com"),
("abc","defd", "abc.def@test.com"),
("abc","defd", "abc.deqf@test.com"),
("aabc","def", "aabc.def123@test.com")]).toDF("na","la","em")
tdf.where("em like concat(na,'.',la,'%@test.com')").show()

#output
+----+---+--------------------+
|  na| la|                  em|
+----+---+--------------------+
| abc|def|    abc.def@test.com|
|aabc|def|aabc.def123@test.com|
+----+---+--------------------+
```